# Determining if a relation is reflexive

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix (list of lists) of zeros and ones, representing relation. I need to determine whether this relation is reflexive.

I know that a 1-0 matrix representing a relation is reflexive if the diagonals are all 1. I don't know what to do next.

Example matrix (answer should be "reflexive"):

```
matrix = [
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matrix = [ [ 1, 0, 0, 1, ...], [0, 1, ...], ...]
assert all(len(row)==len(matrix) for row in matrix) # check whether both dimensions are the same
if all(matrix[i][i] == 1 for i in range(len(matrix))):
    print("Relation is reflexive")
else:
    print("Relation is not reflexive")
```